# Use .Contains() in EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, contains

I use the following Linq Query:

```
var projectList = from p in dbContext.vw_Projektkontrolle
                       where p.TXT_Adress1.Contains(filterTxt)
                       orderby p.TXT_Name
                       select p;
```

**My `projectList` is always null.** In the debugging I can see, that `filterTxt` is for example "testcompany".

> Is the Contains method still in use in EF 6 or is there any work
>   around?

**I pass the `filterTxt` via Form Post to the Action Method in my MVC application.**

how to fix this issue.

> **EDIT:** it works when I use just one `char` f.ex: "a" as `filterTxt`.
>
> But `TXT_Adress1` and `filterTxt` are both declared as strings

Comment: Contains here is the String method and not related to entity framework. Be sure that dbContext.vw_Projektkontrolle contains elements with TXT_Adress1 contains filter text.

Comment: Have you tried using Lambda expression? Something like `var projectList = dbContext.vw_Projektkontrolle.Where(x => x.TXT_Adress1.Contains(filterTxt)).OrderBy(o => o.TXT_Name).ToList();`

Comment: I've tried Lambda and the result was the same. Nothing.
I am absolutely sure that TXT_Adress1 has the filterTxt in it, so I'm wondering why it doeasnt append the filter to the string. @SelvaTS

Comment: Have you checked what is the query formed in the EF?

Comment: Make sure that the casing is the same. Pretty sure case sensitivity applies here. Use `.ToLower()`

Comment: You're getting a lot of confusing comments here. People, LINQ (also goes for fluent syntax) will be translated to SQL by Entity Framework. .NET's `string.Contains()` will not be called. Also, the case-sensitivity depends on the database collation. So please OP, show the data that's in your database and the `filterTxt` you're searching for.

Comment: @MNF that was my first thought to but then i remembered that Linq2SQL converts string contains to a SQL function, thought don't recall exactly how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.Contains method translates to:

```
CHARINDEX(ShowTypeDescriptio, @showTypeDescription) > 0
```

Might try to use lower case:

```
var projectList = from p in dbContext.vw_Projektkontrolle
                   where p.TXT_Adress1.ToLower().Contains(filterTxt.ToLower())
                   orderby p.TXT_Name
                   select p;
```

And even if it works you might face [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html) issue

Comment: That worked! I tried it with toUpper() and it didn't work. Thx man you helpt me a lot :)